# How to verify SMS sender? Prevent spoofing

Tags: security, authentication, sms, spoofing

I essentially have the same question as this one:
[Dealing with SMS Spoofing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923591/dealing-with-sms-spoofing)
however, I feel as though his question was not thoroughly answered and it is also several years old and there may be a new strategy. I would like to impliment an SMS service and I would not like people to be able to spoof numbers from my customers. SMS spoofing services exist, so, how can one verify a text message that has arrived to be real? I am not well versed on text message protocol, are there headers or something that I could read to confirm a user identity after an initial verification code or something?

Comment: Caller ID is spoofable by design, it's not designed to be a security measure. Your only option for SMS is to ask for a per-user, secret value to be present in the message body for the message to be considered genuine.

Comment: @AndréB. That's what I thought might be the answer, but I was hoping it wasn't. Perhaps add this as an answer. You may get the point if nobody else has any other suggestions.